# Lumen and Mandrill - Undefined index: secret

Tags: laravel-5.1, mandrill, lumen

I have a simple site build with `Lumen` and I need to send emails using `Mandrill`.

I have set up in the `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mandrill_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=mandrill_api_key
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email_address
MAIL_FROM_NAME=email_name
```

In the route `test` I added this code, just to check if it works:

```
Mail::send( 'emails.gift', $dati, function ( $message ) use ( $dati )
{
    $message->to( $dati['email'], $dati['nome'] . ' ' . $dati['cognome'] )->subject( 'Scarica il tuo regalo.' );
} );
```

But when I try to send the email I get:

```
ErrorException in TransportManager.php line 116:
Undefined index: secret
```

In Lumen there is no the `services.php` file, so where should I set the secret?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own `services.php` file. With the path: `your-lumen-project/config/services.php` same as [Laravel services.php path](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/services.php)

```
your-lumen-project/
    app/
    config/
        services.php
```

**services.php** content:

```
<?php

return [
    'mandrill' => [
        'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET')
    ],
];
```

Then put `MANDRILL_SECRET=yoursecretkey` in your `.env` file.

Done!